# I am using RecyclerView with fragment but my list is not showing on clicking video icon of bottom navigation in my app. app is showing no error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

here is my videofragment.i just want to show list view after clicking video menu of bottom navigation bar.but list view is not showing.I am new to android studio.please help me.this is my videofragment code.

**VideoFragment.java**

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<String> chapterNames=new ArrayList<>();



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos,container,false);

    chapterNames.add("chapter 1");
    chapterNames.add("chapter 2");
    chapterNames.add("chapter 3");
    chapterNames.add("chapter 4");


    ListView listChapters=view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,chapterNames);
    listChapters.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    return view;
}}
```

**fragment_video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> here is my main activity where i used fragment transaction.all other fragment is working well but when i am clicking on video icon menu from bottom nav bar then it is not showing list view.
>   **ActivityMain.xml**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
     if(fragment!=null){
      getSupportFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.fragment_layout,fragment)
              .commit();
       return true;
     }
     return false;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
  Fragment fragment=null;

  switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
      case R.id.navigation_home:
          fragment=new HomeFragment();
          break;

      case R.id.navigation_videos:
          fragment=new VideoFragment();
          break;

      case R.id.navigation_courses:
          fragment=new CoursesFragment();
          break;
      case R.id.navigation_aboutus:
          fragment=new AboutusFragment();
          break;
  }

  return loadFragment(fragment);
  }
 }
```

**Full logcat**

```
     09/18 00:05:16: Launching 'app' on Realme RMX1825.
 $ adb shell am start -n 
 "com.example.dronschool/com.example.dronschool.MainActivity" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
 Waiting for application to come online: com.example.dronschool.test | 
com.example.dronschool
Connecting to com.example.dronschool
 Waiting for application to start debug server
 Waiting for application to come online: com.example.dronschool.test | 
  com.example.dronschool
  Connecting to com.example.dronschool
  Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior 
  can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings 
 page.
  I/System.out: Debugger has connected
  waiting for debugger to settle...
 Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
 I/chatty: uid=10207(com.example.dronschool) identical 2 lines
  I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
  I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 I/chatty: uid=10207(com.example.dronschool) identical 2 lines
  I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
  I/System.out: debugger has settled (1332)
 W/mple.dronschool: type=1400 audit(0.0:143126): avc: denied { search } for 
  name="/" dev="mmcblk0p38" ino=2 
  scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c207,c256,c512,c768 
  tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
  D/Bard_Injector: isFlipFontUsed = false
  E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
  Blocked msg = { when=-2s950ms what=110 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H 
 obj=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{a4e59e2 com.example.dronschool}} } 
 , cost  = 2930 ms
   >>>Current msg List is:
   E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-2s946ms what=159 
   target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction hashCode, 
  mActivityToken = android.os.BinderProxy@98b5173 }
 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-2s945ms what=159 
 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction hashCode, 
      mActivityToken = android.os.BinderProxy@98b5173 }
   E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=-2s945ms what=0 
  target=android.app.ActivityThread$H 
     callback=com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl }
       E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4>  = { when=-2s944ms what=0 
    target=android.app.ActivityThread$H 
    callback=com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl }
    E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5>  = { when=-2s944ms what=149 
   target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@98b5173 }
   E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <6>  = { when=-2s452ms what=159 
     target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction hashCode, 
      mActivityToken = android.os.BinderProxy@98b5173 }
     E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <7>  = { when=-2s452ms what=137 
      target=android.app.ActivityThread$H arg1=1 
    obj=android.os.BinderProxy@98b5173 }
   >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
  W/mple.dronschoo: create CommonDcsHelper
    cacheJniMembers success
     constructJavaHashMap: start
      constructJavaHashMap: end
    sendCommonDcs: start
       W/mple.dronschoo: sendCommonDcs: end
      Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;- 


 >computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z 
  (light greylist, reflection)
   W/mple.dronschoo: constructJavaHashMap: start
   W/mple.dronschoo: constructJavaHashMap: end
   sendCommonDcs: start
  W/mple.dronschoo: sendCommonDcs: end
     Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;- 
  >makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
  I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = 
   com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@ff05f8e
   I/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@a79ff45[MainActivity], 
    this=android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@616e69a, 
  pkg=com.example.dronschool
    D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , 
  fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = 
   false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
   W/InputTransport: ARC dlopen LIB: libARC.so fail with dlopen failed: 
     library "libARC.so" not found
     I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x7ae25316e0
   V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = 
   android.view.ViewRootImpl@71f4bcb, this = DecorView@a79ff45[MainActivity]
      I/Choreographer: Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too 
    much work on its main thread.
  D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7ad05e3000)
   I/ConfigStore:
```

android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7ad05e3000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/Choreographer: Skipped 6 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:143128): avc: denied { search } for name="/" dev="mmcblk0p38" ino=2 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c207,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
     I/Choreographer: Skipped 3 frames!  The application may be doing too much work 
         on its main thread.

Comment: This requires more context. Where is your ListView in XML? Also, are you instantiating your fragment correctly? Perhaps post how you are instantiating your fragment in your OnClickListener.

Comment: Please post your full logcat

Comment: now i edited my problem correctly.

Comment: @Jacob i have posted above my full logcat